# Проблема во время скроллинга страницы

Tags: javascript, css

Я используя .append создал кнопку которая появляется после нажатия другой кнопки,
и кнопка отобразилась не с первого раза, но потом все таки отобразилась,только уже 
появилась проблема, при прокрутке колесиком мышки кнопка меняет место вслед за прокруткой мыши. Кнопка появляется в пустом `div`, код скрипта

```
$(but1).on('click', function(){ $('#div3').append('<button id="but2">CLICK!</button>');}
```

код css кнопки

```
#but2 {position: static; border-style: outset; position: fixed; text-align: right; z-index: 5;}
```

Как прикрепить ее к месту?

Comment: У вас кнопка с фиксированной позицией.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чёт у вас дурь какая-то))) и z-index и position:fixed.

http://htmlbook.ru/css/position

Почитайте на досуге.

И главный вопрос: зачем вы кнопку добавляете средствами JS??? Это же та ещё наркомания. Не проще ли её просто скрывать средствами CSS???